# Document.ready is not fired second time after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have created a button in a view in Php codeignter.

**View**

```
<div id=div_signup>
      <input id="btnRegisterID" name="btnRegister" style="margin-right: 5px;" value="Register" type="button" class="btn btn-success"/>
</div
```

**Controller**

```
  public function register()
    {

        $this->load->view('MAIN\view_Register');

    }
```

On click of this button I am making an ajax call and On success I am re-binding same view within a signup div again. 
Which means after first event now button is reloaded by view.

**Ajax call:**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        {

 $("#btnRegisterID").on("click", function()
            {
                     $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'http://localhost/Voyager/Main/register',
                data:{},
                success:function(){
              $("#div_signup").load('http://localhost/Voyager/Main/register');
                },
                failure:function(){
              alert("nooo"); 
                }             
            });
        });          
});
```

On first click it works fine, ajax call is successful.

But on second click nothing is happening.

There is no error in browser console.

Can someone help with this.

Am I missing here something?

**Update:**
On success on ajax call I changed above code to location.reload(). Still issue isn't resolved.

```
 success:function(){
              location.reload();
                },
```

Comment: Looks like the content is cached because the url is not changed (it has already been loaded the first time).

Comment: Any way to avoid this? I ammaking ajax call so url is going to be same

Comment: to be sure you should place some log (`console.log`) in the `success` callback to see if it's actually called or not. I'm just guessing so there is not any idea about the solution here.

Comment: I am trying to check that with alert in document.ready() part, but its not called at all. not eve document.ready

Comment: in your `success` callback, you just load content for your `div`. So how could that trigger document.ready the second time?

Comment: Didnt get you. Isn't remaining page is ready? Are you suggesting any other approach to this?

Comment: Also, I tried with location.reload() in success. I will update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking button outside that Panel worked for me partially.

However there was issue with my architecture in view. It is not possible to partially load a view in jquery without complete page refresh keeping data uptodate.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change you button click event to like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnRegisterID', function () {
// You ajax Code

})
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS
IN SUCCESS REMOVE

```
$("#div_signup").load('http://localhost/Voyager/Main/register');
```

REPLACE

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: No change. Still second time its not firing.

Comment: $('body').on('click','#btnRegisterID',function(){

Comment: Made this change too. Still no effect on second click

Comment: location.reload() is refreshing the page. Can i acheieve this without refresing page??

Comment: $("#div_signup").load('http://localhost/Voyager/Main/register'); just remove this

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.reload()` instead of location.reload();